# Can a mouse/keyboard wireless USB anthena be hacked to transmit data?

Tags: usb, data-transfer, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard

I just watched [Jacob Appelbaum's talk at 30C3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vILAlhwUgIU) and he explained how some USB devices have this capability built in.
My question is: Could a Windows infected computer (given) mess with an USB which is plugged into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some devices has been built as `SDR` - Software-Defined Radio. Their behaviour completely controlled by software, driver or/and application. The only restriction is physical - frequences, stability, signal-to-noise ratio etc. One single device can act as WiFi-dongle, LTE-dongle, DVB-receiver, FM-receiver and so on. Some manufacturers restrict device functionality in drivers, but it is still capable to do much more under control of "other" software.

Answer (score 2):

Wireless mice/keyboards transmit data by design, so your question is hard to follow. Could a device like this send data other than what it was initially designed and intended to send? Absolutely. Could an infected computer connected to one of these devices do this? Absolutely. People are frequently changing the purpose of these peripherals, many for hobby.

Comment: I meant the receiver anthena be reversed to transmit data to a cell phone per se.